# This values for arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am trying to understand arrow functions in ECMAScript 6.

This is the definition I came across while reading:

> Arrow functions have implicit `this` binding, which means that the
>   value of the `this` value inside of an arrow function is aways the
>   same as the value of `this` in the scope in which the arrow function
>   is defined!

According to the definition, I believe `this` for an `arrow function` should contain the same block level values that the arrow function was defined in.

Code:

```
var test = {
  id: "123123",
  k: {
    laptop: "ramen",
    testfunc: () => console.log(this)
  }
}

console.log(test.k.testfunc);
```

However, I am getting this result from the code

```
function testfunc() {
    return console.log(undefined);
}
```

What I thought I would get would be an output of:

```
{"laptop": "ramen"}
```

if I ran this

`console.log(test.k.testfunc());`

Comment: When using `console.log( test.k.testfunc() );` in FF (note the parentheses at the end), I get a reference to window. Which is correct as when defining the function, the current scope was `window` in my case.

Comment: this should help explain:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

"this". See what I did there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's transform into the equivalent ES5 code:

```
var test = {
  id: "123123",
  k: {
    laptop: "ramen",
    testfunc: function(){return console.log(this)}.bind(this)
  }
}
```

Remember that `this` depends on **how** you call the function. The outer `this` isn't inside a function, so it will default to `undefined` in strict mode.

Simplified scenario below:

```
console.log(this) // undefined

var test = {
  a: this // same `this` as above
}
```

Comment: @natebarbettini  Arrow functions inherit 'this' from their enclosing scope (function scope), so interestingly, this will work - testfunc: function() { ()=>{console.log(this)}() }

Answer (score 3):

You are defining the arrow function in the same scope that you defined `var test`. If you are defining `test` in the global scope, then the arrow function's context will be the global scope too.

If you are defining test inside of a method, the arrow function will share the method's context.

```
function method() {
  const self = this;

  const test = {
    foo: () => console.log(self === this);
  }

  test.foo()
  // console: true
}
```