# Arrow functions not working in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Below method works fine

```
var DBBox = React.createClass({
  loadArticlesFromServer: function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: this.props.url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {username:data.username,isPublished:data.isPublished, heading:data.heading},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({data: data});
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
},
```

But if I change method declaration to arrow function on line 2 like this

```
loadArticlesFromServer: ()=> {  //error - Cannot read property 'props' of undefined at line 6
```

or

```
loadArticlesFromServer= ()=> {  //Syntax error
```

Am I using arrow function incorrectly or missing something? or is it not supported? I am using chrome and tried enabling harmony flag without any luck.

Comment: You should study the behaviors of the `this` in the arrow functions. You can't use `bind` with arrows.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647507/this-values-for-arrow-functions) (no pun intended)

Comment: Thanks @Redu , pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrow function expressions are best suited for non-method functions. Let's see what happens when we try to use them as methods.

```
'use strict';
var obj = {
  i: 10,
  b: () => console.log(this.i, this),
  c: function() {
    console.log( this.i, this)
  }
}
obj.b(); // prints undefined, Window
obj.c(); // prints 10, Object {...}
```